# Get a list (object in new line) and print a list in one line

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I want a user to input a list with object in every new line. The user will copy and past a whole list to the program and not enter a new object every time.

For example, here is the users input:

> january
>       february
>       march
>       april
>       may
>       june

and he gets a list just like this:

```
('january','february','march','april','may','june')
```

Someone has an idea for a python code that can help me?

Comment: You must show your what you have tried before ask to get a solution for your problem

Comment: Got an answer ready, what have you done so far before I post it?

Comment: The thing is that i use pycharm and i cant even input list with object in a new line using raw|_input

Comment: If your using python 2, you can do `x= input()` and the user can input a literal list like `[1,2,3]` and a list will be returned

Comment: @muddyfish: Please don't encourage new programmers to use Python 2's dangerous `input()` function.

Comment: dont worry Im using raw_input only, and I want the input to be a vertical list, thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
sentinel = ''
print list(iter(raw_input, sentinel))
```

Execute the program, copy paste your vertical string.You will get

```
['january','february','march','april','may','june']
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the iter() function ?

Answer (score 0):

`splitlines()` returns a `list` with all the lines in string.

```
>>> str = '''january
... february
... march
... april
... may
... june'''    
>>> str.splitlines() # returns a list
['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june']
>>> tuple(str.splitlines()) # you can convert to tuple like this
('january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june')
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple method, waits until the user types in a newline.

```
def get_list(prompt=""):
    output=[]
    inp = ""
    while inp != "\n":
        output.append(inp)
        inp = raw_input(prompt)
    output=output[1:]
    return output
```